# Can not open soft keyboard in EditText control

Tags: android

I want to create 1 edit text with the below condition:
- User can not focus on this control in normal.
- When user click on this control, soft-keyborad is displayed and user can input into this control
- When user press enter on this soft-keyborad or back on device, it is closed and back to normal view with control is not focus.

I tried the below code but not work :(
When starting, control is not focus: ok

When click on control, at the first click, control is focus but not display soft-keyborad

In the second click, display soft-keyborad

- When press enter button in soft-keyborad: back to screen with control is not focus: OK
- When press back button device, back to screen with control is still focus : not ok

  ```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
  final EditText txtSearch = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.p60004_txt_search_str);
  txtSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          txtSearch.setFocusable(true);//(false);
          txtSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
          txtSearch.requestFocus();
      }
  });
  txtSearch.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                  (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
              {
                  String strSearch = txtSearch.getText().toString();
                  if (strSearch != null && strSearch != ""){
                          searchFriend(UserAPIConstants.FRIEND_SEARCH_TYPE_SC, strSearch);
                  }

                  hideSoftKeyboard(v);
                  txtSearch.setFocusable(false);
                  txtSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

              }

          return false;
      }
  });
  public void hideSoftKeyboard (View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
  ```

Comment: I don't quite follow you. If the user cannot focus on `txtSearch` (condition #1), how can the user click on `txtSearch` to enter text (condition #2)?

Comment: "below code but not work" .. what part didn't work? Or the entire code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your xml which has edittext put these values for the layout node

   ```
    android:focusable="true" 
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   ```

   and dont put any focusable or focusable in touch mode attributes for your edittext..
2. Then in your code in onKey method remove thse lines..

   ```
    txtSearch.setFocusable(false);
      txtSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
   ```

   and put

   ```
    txtSearch.clearFocus();
   ```
3. And You should override this method

   ```
   onBackPressed()
   ```

   like this..

   ```
    @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
    txtSearch.clearFocus();
    //hide the soft keyboard..

     }
   ```

Comment: i tried clearFocus but it does not work
besides, onBackPressed does not work also

Comment: Which api are you using?I did the same just now.. and it works fine for me.. :|

Comment: @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
   EditText a = ((EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.p60004_txt_search_str));
   a.clearFocus();
   //hide the soft keyboard..
   hideSoftKeyboard(a);
   }

Comment: what you mean? i just use android 2.2 and call txtSearch.clearFocus

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10210/discussion-between-raju-and-ankata)

Answer (score 0):

try commenting

```
hidekeyboard(v);
```

and the changes that Alex Lockwood suggested.

Answer (score 0):

use this in `onClick()`

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

to close the keypad use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```